# Oculus Quest: Unable to Generate VS project for C++

Tags: unreal-engine4, oculus

I'm running Unreal Engine v4.24 and trying to generate a VS project to develop in C++, but I don't have an option to create it. 
I have my project launching and can play it on my Quest, but am stuck on this:

[image]

I know that I can't compille Native plugins to work with Android but I don't see why I can't create a project for this engine, any help will be appreaciated.

Comment: Take a look here and see if this helps: [https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/19807-which-program-to-associate-a-uproject-with](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/19807-which-program-to-associate-a-uproject-with)

Comment: No unfortunately I'm able to launch the engine and the project, I just don't have access to generating the VS project that I need to use with C++.

Comment: Did you take a lookup a the Youtube video? Sorry, I should have just pasted a direct link to it [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZu5EB2UfiA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZu5EB2UfiA)

Comment: When I follow those steps it's still asking for the C++ source files: [Image of Error](https://ibb.co/xsHSbhD)

Comment: Sorry, that worked for me in the past. The only other thing I can think of is making sure that your Visual Studio installation has game development with C++ under workloads installed

Comment: No problem, I installed everything I could as well from the VS installer that's even related to Unreal and nothing :,(

Answer (score 0):

In order to force a generation you need to click on 'New C++ class' then you'll be able to access the source:
[image]